# Why isn't a data class with @Serializable convertible to a java.io.Serializable class?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I have added a Kotlin library which contained a class like

```
@Serializable data class Dog(@SerialName("age")val age: Int);
```

I tried to put it as an intent extra like

```
intent.putExtra("data", d); //d is an instance of Dog
```

but the IDE showed no such argument overload error. I also tried manually converting like

```
intent.putExtra("data", d as java.io.Serializable);
```

but the IDE said "The cast can never succeed". I wondered if `@Serializable` is a different thing from `java.io.Serializable`, but it was the same thing:

```
internal actual typealias Serializable = java.io.Serializable
```

So, why can't I put that class instance as an extra?

Comment: Did you tried by extending it from `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: You should implement `Serializable` .. Check the de-compiled version of Dog class . it does not implement `Serializable` and that's what a Bundle needs .. I never used kotlin Serialization myself till now it seems like a `Encoding/decoding` thing not exactly equivalent to java.io.Serialization in this term ..

Comment: I believe your class probably uses `kotlinx.serialization.Serializable`. Which I think is different from `java.io.Serializable`. I'm not entirely sure though

Comment: @Ivo It's not "my" class, but a class in a library, and there are these two lines at the beginning of the class file, `import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName; import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable`. But when I middle-clicked `@Serializable` in the IDE, it jumped to `internal actual typealias Serializable = java.io.Serializable`. So, in this case, there is no way to put that class's instance into the intent's extra?

Comment: You mention that the **IDE** says the cast can never succeed. But what about the compiler? That is to say, have you tried compiling and running the code? Do you still get that error or does it actually work?

Comment: @Slaw I think the IDE (Android Studio) warned about a runtime error, not a compile-time error. It was compiled, but when that line was executed, the app crashed with `java.lang.ClassCastException: Dog cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`.